# Using QtWebEngine with X forwarding

Tags: qt, qtwebengine

I just can't get webengine working. This is my source code:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWebEngineWidgets/QWebEngineView>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWebEngineView view;
    view.setUrl(QUrl(QStringLiteral("http://www.qt.io")));
    view.resize(1024, 750);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

And this happens when I try to run it:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -I/usr/include/qt -fPIC -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Widgets -lQt5WebEngine -lQt5WebEngineWidgets && ./a.out
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
```

No windows is shown and it just hangs there until I kill it with `^C`. How can I get it to work?

Comment: on what operation system are your working?

Comment: maybe this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834254/steam-libgl-error-no-matching-fbconfigs-or-visuals-found-libgl-error-failed-t/847980) can help

Comment: @Simon hm I kinda forgot that information, server machine I ssh into is archlinux, host is windows 7 with cygwin and it's X server implementation.